# Публикация Job artifacts

Tags: gitlab-ci

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где выставляются настройки автоматической публикации артифакта джобы ci gitlab?
Вводная: после выполнения джобы сохраняется некий отчет с файлами где один из файлов index.html
В гитлаб есть возможность перейти к артифакту и сразу открыть файлик index.html после чего откроется страница отчета
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема: на рабочей гитлаб нет данной стрелочки и переход соответсвенно невозможен.
Подскажите, где выставляются данные настройки?